# screen scraping

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

i am screen scraping a website which is in danish language.. i am unable to scrape certain characters as like må ..
any idea to solve this?
thanks

Comment: Will you show us the relevant code you're using to scrape the content?

Comment: What library/code are you using to scrape?

Comment: i am not using library files.. i am just using regex

Comment: Oh my... Take a look at this why you shouldn't be using regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @sam I don't know the structure of your website, but if you're scraping only one website and it's half-way decently built, I'd consider you chunking it and parsing the relevant information with a find-in-string function or similar. But of course, I have no clue what you're doing so I'm afraid we're of limited help until you fill us in :-)

Comment: an example : The website displays text like this "Dine behov - vores mål!"
when i right click and view source of the page, the same content displays like this
Dine behov - vores m&#229;l!

i feel like it has to do with charset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just used System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode()
it works ..

Answer (score 1):

Try UTF-8 or Windows-1252 charset.

Comment: thanks ..i tried that..here website has " windows-1252" encoding

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Web browser control, you can set the page encoding to whatever language that can show that character.  Then just extract the page source.

Answer (score 0):

I use iso-8859-1 for decoding. 
HTH

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use the same encoding that the HttpWebResponse object has, 
Below is the code that will work with all langauges and characters .

```
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string Charset = response.CharacterSet;

        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(Charset);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            response_stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);

            html = response_stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
```